# Problem with Epilog and GridLines

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have plotted some logarithmic curves using **LogLogPlot**.

In this case, I wanted to add two vertical lines to the plot; I used **Epilog**, but it seems that it does not work with LogLogPlot.
Instead, I used **GridLines**.
But now, the problem is that I cannot allocate two colors for my lines. Only the first color works.

Why is that?

```
 GridLines -> {{1, 8}, None}, 
 GridLinesStyle -> {{Directive[Black, Dashed]}, {Directive[Red}}
```

Here is an example: I want to add several vertical lines in different colors.
[image]

Comment: Please create a minimal example and draw by hand (if necessary) the output that you are looking for.

Comment: @Syed thanks. I edited that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
LogLogPlot[{Log[x]^x, x^x}, {x, 0.1, 10}, PlotLabels -> "Expressions",
  GridLines -> {{{1, 
     Directive@{AbsoluteThickness[2], Green, Dashed}}, {8, 
     Directive@{Opacity[1], AbsoluteThickness[2], Red, Dashed}}}, None}
 ]
```

[image]